# Traefik http shows text on page, but https shows "404 page not found"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I want to be able to visit the https of my site which just shows text but it shows a 404 error message.

The error is 404 page not found
I don't have tls set up but I was under the impression that if I don't have it set up then the browser would just show the warning but would still let me see the content. The browser says the content is not secure but the page just shows 404 page not found

**example-app.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
namespace: example
name: 'example-app-main'
labels:
app: 'example-app-main'
tier: 'frontend'
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: 'example-app'
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: 'example-app'
spec:
containers:
- name: example-app-container
image: richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest
imagePullPolicy: Always
env:
- name: SSH_KEY
value: 'key'
- name: GIT_REPO
value: 'name@source.git'
- name: GIT_EMAIL
value: 'email@email.com'
- name: GIT_NAME
value: 'example'
ports:
- containerPort: 80
```

**example-ingress.yml**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
namespace: example
name: example-ingress
annotations:
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
spec:
rules:
- host: mydomain.com
http:
paths:
- path: /
backend:
serviceName: example-app
servicePort: 80
example-service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
namespace: example
name: 'example-app'
spec:
type: ClusterIP
ports:
- protocol: TCP
name: web
port: 80
targetPort: 80
- protocol: TCP
name: websecure
port: 443
targetPort: 443
selector:
app: 'example-app'
```

**Traefik helm values file**

```
# Default values for Traefik
image:
name: traefik
tag: 2.2.8
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

#
# Configure the deployment
#
deployment:
enabled: true
# Number of pods of the deployment
replicas: 1
# Additional deployment annotations (e.g. for jaeger-operator sidecar injection)
annotations: {}
# Additional pod annotations (e.g. for mesh injection or prometheus scraping)
podAnnotations: {}
# Additional containers (e.g. for metric offloading sidecars)
additionalContainers: []
# Additional initContainers (e.g. for setting file permission as shown below)
initContainers: []
# The "volume-permissions" init container is required if you run into permission issues.
# Related issue: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/6972
# - name: volume-permissions
# image: busybox:1.31.1
# command: ["sh", "-c", "chmod -Rv 600 /data/*"]
# volumeMounts:
# - name: data
# mountPath: /data
# Custom pod DNS policy. Apply if \hostNetwork: true``
# dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet

# Pod disruption budget
podDisruptionBudget:
enabled: false
# maxUnavailable: 1
# minAvailable: 0

# Create an IngressRoute for the dashboard
ingressRoute:
dashboard:
enabled: true
# Additional ingressRoute annotations (e.g. for kubernetes.io/ingress.class)
annotations: {}
# Additional ingressRoute labels (e.g. for filtering IngressRoute by custom labels)
labels: {}

rollingUpdate:
maxUnavailable: 1
maxSurge: 1


#
# Configure providers
#
providers:
kubernetesCRD:
enabled: true
kubernetesIngress:
enabled: true
# IP used for Kubernetes Ingress endpoints
publishedService:
enabled: false
# Published Kubernetes Service to copy status from. Format: namespace/servicename
# By default this Traefik service
# pathOverride: ""

#
# Add volumes to the traefik pod.
# This can be used to mount a cert pair or a configmap that holds a config.toml file.
# After the volume has been mounted, add the configs into traefik by using the \additionalArguments` list below, eg:`
# additionalArguments:
# - "--providers.file.filename=/config/dynamic.toml"
volumes: []
# - name: public-cert
# mountPath: "/certs"
# type: secret
# - name: configs
# mountPath: "/config"
# type: configMap

# Logs
# https://docs.traefik.io/observability/logs/
logs:
# Traefik logs concern everything that happens to Traefik itself (startup, configuration, events, shutdown, and so on).
general:
# By default, the logs use a text format (common), but you can
# also ask for the json format in the format option
# format: json
# By default, the level is set to ERROR. Alternative logging levels are DEBUG, PANIC, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, and INFO.
level: ERROR
access:
# To enable access logs
enabled: true
# By default, logs are written using the Common Log Format (CLF).
# To write logs in JSON, use json in the format option.
# If the given format is unsupported, the default (CLF) is used instead.
# format: json
# To write the logs in an asynchronous fashion, specify a bufferingSize option.
# This option represents the number of log lines Traefik will keep in memory before writing
# them to the selected output. In some cases, this option can greatly help performances.
# bufferingSize: 100
# Filtering https://docs.traefik.io/observability/access-logs/#filtering
filters: {}
# statuscodes: "200,300-302"
# retryattempts: true
# minduration: 10ms
# Fields
# https://docs.traefik.io/observability/access-logs/#limiting-the-fieldsincluding-headers
fields:
general:
defaultmode: keep
names: {}
# Examples:
# ClientUsername: drop
headers:
defaultmode: drop
names: {}
# Examples:
# User-Agent: redact
# Authorization: drop
# Content-Type: keep

globalArguments:
- "--global.checknewversion"
- "--global.sendanonymoususage"

#
# Configure Traefik static configuration
# Additional arguments to be passed at Traefik's binary
# All available options available on https://docs.traefik.io/reference/static-configuration/cli/
## Use curly braces to pass values: \helm install --set="additionalArguments={--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik-internal,--log.level=DEBUG}"``
additionalArguments: []
# - "--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik-internal"
# - "--log.level=DEBUG"

# Environment variables to be passed to Traefik's binary
env: []
# - name: SOME_VAR
# value: some-var-value
# - name: SOME_VAR_FROM_CONFIG_MAP
# valueFrom:
# configMapRef:
# name: configmap-name
# key: config-key
# - name: SOME_SECRET
# valueFrom:
# secretKeyRef:
# name: secret-name
# key: secret-key

envFrom: []
# - configMapRef:
# name: config-map-name
# - secretRef:
# name: secret-name

# Configure ports
ports:
# The name of this one can't be changed as it is used for the readiness and
# liveness probes, but you can adjust its config to your liking
traefik:
port: 9000
# Use hostPort if set.
# hostPort: 9000
#
# Use hostIP if set. If not set, Kubernetes will default to 0.0.0.0, which
# means it's listening on all your interfaces and all your IPs. You may want
# to set this value if you need traefik to listen on specific interface
# only.
# hostIP: 192.168.100.10

# Defines whether the port is exposed if service.type is LoadBalancer or
# NodePort.
#
# You SHOULD NOT expose the traefik port on production deployments.
# If you want to access it from outside of your cluster,
# use \kubectl proxy` or create a secure ingress`
expose: false
# The exposed port for this service
exposedPort: 9000
# The port protocol (TCP/UDP)
protocol: TCP
web:
port: 8000
# hostPort: 8000
expose: true
exposedPort: 80
# The port protocol (TCP/UDP)
protocol: TCP
# Use nodeport if set. This is useful if you have configured Traefik in a
# LoadBalancer
# nodePort: 32080
# Port Redirections
# Added in 2.2, you can make permanent redirects via entrypoints.
# https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#redirection
# redirectTo: websecure
websecure:
port: 8443
# hostPort: 8443
expose: true
exposedPort: 443
# The port protocol (TCP/UDP)
protocol: TCP
# nodePort: 32443

# Options for the main traefik service, where the entrypoints traffic comes
# from.
service:
enabled: true
type: LoadBalancer
# Additional annotations (e.g. for cloud provider specific config)
annotations: {}
# Additional entries here will be added to the service spec. Cannot contains
# type, selector or ports entries.
spec: {}
# externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
# loadBalancerIP: "1.2.3.4"
# clusterIP: "2.3.4.5"
loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
# - 192.168.0.1/32
# - 172.16.0.0/16
externalIPs: []
# - 1.2.3.4

## Create HorizontalPodAutoscaler object.
##
autoscaling:
enabled: false
# minReplicas: 1
# maxReplicas: 10
# metrics:
# - type: Resource
# resource:
# name: cpu
# targetAverageUtilization: 60
# - type: Resource
# resource:
# name: memory
# targetAverageUtilization: 60

# Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
# ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
# After the pvc has been mounted, add the configs into traefik by using the \additionalArguments` list below, eg:`
# additionalArguments:
# - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/data/acme.json"
# It will persist TLS certificates.
persistence:
enabled: false
# existingClaim: ""
accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
size: 128Mi
# storageClass: ""
path: /data
annotations: {}
# subPath: "" # only mount a subpath of the Volume into the pod

# If hostNetwork is true, runs traefik in the host network namespace
# To prevent unschedulabel pods due to port collisions, if hostNetwork=true
# and replicas>1, a pod anti-affinity is recommended and will be set if the
# affinity is left as default.
hostNetwork: false

# Whether Role Based Access Control objects like roles and rolebindings should be created
rbac:
enabled: true

# If set to false, installs ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding so Traefik can be used across namespaces.
# If set to true, installs namespace-specific Role and RoleBinding and requires provider configuration be set to that same namespace
namespaced: false

# The service account the pods will use to interact with the Kubernetes API
serviceAccount:
# If set, an existing service account is used
# If not set, a service account is created automatically using the fullname template
name: ""

# Additional serviceAccount annotations (e.g. for oidc authentication)
serviceAccountAnnotations: {}

resources: {}
# requests:
# cpu: "100m"
# memory: "50Mi"
# limits:
# cpu: "300m"
# memory: "150Mi"
affinity: {}
# # This example pod anti-affinity forces the scheduler to put traefik pods
# # on nodes where no other traefik pods are scheduled.
# # It should be used when hostNetwork: true to prevent port conflicts
# podAntiAffinity:
# requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
# - labelSelector:
# matchExpressions:
# - key: app
# operator: In
# values:
# - {{ template "traefik.name" . }}
# topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []

# Pods can have priority.
# Priority indicates the importance of a Pod relative to other Pods.
priorityClassName: ""

# Set the container security context
# To run the container with ports below 1024 this will need to be adjust to run as root
securityContext:
capabilities:
drop: [ALL]
readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
runAsGroup: 65532
runAsNonRoot: true
runAsUser: 65532

podSecurityContext:
fsGroup: 65532
```

Answer (score 0):

Traefik 2.x does not seem to serve HTTP ingresses any more with the default HTTPS. I think you need to enable TLS for the ingress.